# Spark in cluster mode throws error if a SparkContext is not started

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark job that initializes the spark context only if it is really necessary:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val jobs: List[Job] = ??? //get some jobs
if(jobs.nonEmpty) {
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.parallelize(jobs).foreach(....)
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

It worked fine on Yarn if deploy-mode is 'client'

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

Then I switched deploy mode to 'cluster' and it started to crash in case of `jobs.isEmpty`

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
```

Below is the error text:

> INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
>   application_1509613523426_0017 (state: ACCEPTED) 
>   17/11/02 11:37:17
>
> INFO yarn.Client: Application report for
>   application_1509613523426_0017 (state: FAILED) 17/11/02 11:37:17
>
> INFO yarn.Client:      client token: N/A   diagnostics: Application
>   application_1509613523426_0017 failed 2 times due to AM Container for
>   appattempt_1509613523426_0017_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 For
>   more detailed output, check application tracking
>
> page:http://xxxxxx.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1509613523426_0017Then,
>   click on links to logs of each attempt. Diagnostics: File does not
>   exist:
>   hdfs://xxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1509613523426_0017/__spark_libs__997458388067724499.zip
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://xxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1509613523426_0017/__spark_libs__997458388067724499.zip
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Failing this attempt. Failing the application.     ApplicationMaster
>   host: N/A      ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1      queue: dev      start time:
>   1509622629354      final status: FAILED    tracking URL:
>   http://xxxxxx.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1509613523426_0017      user: xxx Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application
>   application_1509613523426_0017 finished with failed status    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1104)    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1150)  at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   17/11/02 11:37:17 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
>   17/11/02 11:37:17 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
>   /tmp/spark-a5b20def-0218-4b0c-b9f8-fdf8a1802e95

Is it a bug in Yarn support or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SparkContext` is the one who is responsible for communication with cluster manager. If application is submitted to the cluster, but context is never created, YARN cannot determine the state of the application - this is why you get an error.